# Ansible Tower on a Free Linux Distro?

Tags: ansible

Red Hat's Ansible Tower's documentation states that it can only be run on Red Hat Enterprise Linux. I can see once upon a time it could be run on other distros, such as Ubuntu. Is there a free Linux distro that Tower can still be installed upon?

Comment: Have you considered AWX? https://github.com/ansible/awx

Comment: BMitch, great suggestion and I didn't know about it. But the ask is about running Tower on a free distro

Comment: Commercial product requires commercial distros (that's their choice likely for support reasons). But the free upstream project runs on free distros.

Comment: BMitch, fair.. Though Tower did support CentOS, Ubuntu and others until very recently.

Answer (score 1):

The Ansible Tower [Requirements](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/installandreference/requirements_refguide.html) still states

> CentOS 7.7 or later 64-bit (x86)

however

> you must have valid subscriptions attached before installing and running

An other option might be to use [Ansible AWX](https://github.com/ansible/awx)

> AWX provides a web-based user interface, REST API, and task engine built on top of Ansible. It is one of the upstream projects for Red Hat Ansible Automation Platform.

Comment: Thanks, CentOS is apparently going away, so I don't really want to use that going forward. AWX has potential, but it also has a fairly dev-ish installation process, so I'm not sure about it either. I guess how "right" these suggestions are come down to the particular use case. For some these are totally enough.